# Android UsbManager: Retrieve USB drive name

Tags: android, usb

I need the drive name of Pendrive like highlighted in the below image:

[image]

I tried `UsbDevice.getDeviceName()`, `UsbDevice.getProductName()` & `UsbDevice.getManufacturerName()` but none of them giving the drive name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. use `StorageManager`.

```
 StorageManager storage = (StorageManager) getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            List<StorageVolume> volumes = storage.getStorageVolumes();
            for (StorageVolume volume :volumes) {
                Log.d("STORAGE", "Device name:" + volume.getDescription(this));
            }
        }
```

`StorageVolume.getDescription` is having the drive name.

Comment: This works for getting Uuid as well by using volume.getUuid(), works perfectly.